# - The sql-mode strict_trans_tables is enabled in your mysql server, please contact your host provider to disable it

Tags: mysql, sql, mode

How do I disable sql-mode strict_trans_tables? I'm trying to load a program and when I get to load it comes back with - The sql-mode strict_trans_tables is enabled in your mysql server, please contact your host provider to disable it.